# Is there anyone who can give a hint for this Qn

Tags: optimization

$x^* \in R^3$

Maximize: $f(x)$
Subject to: $g_1(x) \le 1$ and $g_2(x) \le 3$

$g_1(x^*) = 1, g_2(x^*) = 2, ∇f(x^*) =4∇g_1(x^*)$ These are given

If first constraint change to $g_1(x) \le 0.99$, but second stays same. Approximately what is the maximum value of $f(x)$?

I tried to solve it by finding lambdas, but I couldn't. Therefore, Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: hint: use the first order conditions of the Lagrangian

Comment: how do I find $\lambda_2$ ? because  I ddon't know $∇g_2(x^*)$

Comment: You can derive $\lambda_2$ from the information that is given. What is the stationarity condition of the unmodified problem?

Comment: @LinAlg: I thought that maximum value is 4.96, but I am not sure

Comment: you should provide some clarification for '4.96'